# Center-block on a row in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to center a row using center-block? I have a roster (4x3) that I need to center in my container-fluid. Been trying to find a solution but it doesn't seem to work..

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QY8BWVrTMW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">1</div>` on the first column.

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-xs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">1</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>         
          <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>         
          <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">3</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>         
          <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See http://www.bootply.com/BFKxufp4m4.

I'm fairly sure the offset is 4. Offsets are great for aligning :)

Comment: Boostrap uses the class `text-center`. No additional code needed (it's already in the core CSS). That said, it doesn't seem as though centering text is what the OP is requesting.